# how to add ripples of this mayavi 3d plot?

Tags: python, numpy, numeric, mayavi

In my plot, I want different colors of ripples. so can you please tell me how to add ripples of this mayavi 3d plot. my code is given bellow.
this is my image [image] i want to add ripples to surface the axis  ripple:sample image:[image]

```
import scipy as np
from mayavi import mlab


x,y = np.mgrid[-3:3:100j, -3:3:100j]

a = 0.3

a0 = 0.2

r1=np.sqrt((x-a)**2 + y**2)

values = np.exp(-r1/a0)



mlab.surf(values, warp_scale='auto')

mlab.outline()

mlab.axes()
# mlab.test_contour3d()
mlab.show()
```

Comment: Can you give more details on "ripple"? Would you happen to have a sample picture of another plot that does have them?

Comment: Hi sir .. i edit my question in that  i add sample image of ripple, like that i want to create my plot,so can you pls tell me sir

Comment: You are plotting a function that's monotonically decreasing with its distance from `(0.3, 0)`, hence no ripples. If you want ripples, you could introduce a oscillating function, say a sine or a cosine of (a multiple of) the distance...

Comment: sir here i am getting the only one ripple of the same color. can i get the more ripples of different color ?

Comment: I changed the all values but i am not getting like that plot sir so is there any other way pls guide me sir?

Comment: I added the `numpy` and `numeric` tags as this question is about producing the data, not much plotting it.

Comment: Change the amplitude (height) and frequency (more ripples) of the oscillation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a static image of 'ripples', try the numpy [sinc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sinc.html) function. That should do what you want. It is the result of Fourier-transforming a delta function.